# 301 redirect all image requests from folder1 to folder2

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Currently I have the following setup:

3 image folders for `big` | `resized` | `thumb`

domain.com/big/image1.jpg

domain.com/resized/image1.jpg

domain.com/thumb/image1.jpg

Since I want to drop the thumb and resized folder, or at least the images in them, I would like to redirect both requests to `resized` and `thumb` to `big`

Many of those images might be indexed by google. So maybe a 301 redirect would be best?

Also changing the .htaccess in resized and thumb would be preferred, since the root htaccess is complicated enough already :)

Goal would be to save a lot of space while merging the SEO of 3 images into 1

Comment: @wurstbrot: You tagged your question with [tag:mod-rewrite] so you know where to get your answer. ;-)

Comment: If I could figure it out on my own, I wouldn't ask here ;) The website is online aswell, so trying too many things isn't smart either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding these rules *above any routing rules* that you may already have:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(resized|thumb)/(.*)$ /big/$2 [L,R=301]
```

But if you prefer to edit the htaccess files in the `resized` and `thumb` directories, you can add these to the htaccess file in those 2 directories:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /big/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Note that by doing this, none of the rules that you have in the root htaccess file will get applied.

Comment: Your root solution redirected to /big/resized or /big/thumb for every image. The in-folder solution works fine. Remove/fix the root solution and I'll accept it as correct answer :) Thanks!

Comment: @Wurstbro Sorry, the first rule should be `$2` and not `$1`.